# Does anyone use Expression Web and Visual Studio together?

Tags: visual-studio, comparison, workflow, expression-web

I'm curious what aspects you use the Expression Web for and what you prefer to do in Visual Studio.

I understand Expression Blend is for making GUI elements of WPF applications, with the programming done in Visual Studio, but *how do Expression Web and Visual Studio fit together?*

Comment: Expression Web is designed for Web-designed so they have very less support of ASP.NET so it's make developer uncomfortable.

Comment: Agreed. Unlike Expression Blend, it's not necessary for the web development at all unless you are a web designer. For RIA, you need to use Blend for Silverlight anyway. Microsoft stopped developing Expression Web maybe because Microsoft finally understood this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression Web is used for the UI design.

Visual Studio is used for programming the underlying model and hooking up to the UI.

They both understand XAML and can share the project/solution structure.

In fact, the were designed to inter-operate in this manner.

Comment: Are you sure Expression web support XAML.I thing you are talking about Blend not individually Expression web. Make your answer clear. Expression web not support XAML expression Blend support it well.

Answer (score 0):

When I've started learning Blend with VS 2010, I've used Expression Blend to make the GUI and and VS for coding. After a time I was only using Visual Studio 2010 for everything. My advice to you is to only use Visual Studio 2010 for complete development of your applications.

Answer (score 0):

I prefers to use Visual Studio for most of my development needs. I briefly used Expression Web but I don't use visual design aids that much so I go back to Visual Studio & Firebug for pretty much all my web developments.

Expression Blend, on the other hand, is the go to tool if you want to do WPF & Silverlight frontend. It speeds up the UI designing process a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is for coding!
Expression is for design!
You can easily use them together. 
If you do a change in one of the the other will prompt you
for this change.
If not just refresh.

If you need to open a page through visual studio right click this page.aspx and 'open with' and find and chose expression blend.

Comment: Both software can not be used on same time.